# combineLatest has different behaviour in Just vs Future

Tags: swift, combine

In Combine there are (among others) these two publishers:

```swift
let just = Just("Just")
let future = Future<String, Never>({ (promise) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        promise(.success("Future"))
    }
})
```

These two have a different output when put into a `combineLatest` publisher like in the following

```swift
just.combineLatest([1,2,3].publisher).sink { (value) in
    print(value)
}.store(in: &bin)
/* prints
("Just", 1)
("Just", 2)
("Just", 3)
*/

future.combineLatest([1,2,3].publisher).sink { (value) in
    print(value)
}.store(in: &bin)
/* prints:
("Future", 3)
*/
```

Is there any way to modify (e.g. an operator) the `Future` publisher in a way so that it will behave like the `Just` publisher?

Comment: It's not the `Future`-as-a-publisher that behaves differently. It's rather, about when the value is emitted. The `Sequence` publisher emits all its values synchronously, and when the future emits *asynchronously*, then it's combined with the "latest" value of `3`. What's your actual problem, because you might be asking an XY question

Answer (score 2):

`Future` doesn't behave differently when you call `combineLatest` on it. Your example is simply flawed due to the async dispatch you add inside your `Future`.

`combineLatest` only emits a value when all of its upstreams emitted a value. So if you add a `DispatchQueue.main.async` before you called `promise` inside your `Future`, you'll delay the emission in your `Future`. Because of this, `Future` will emit later than the `Array.publisher` and hence you'll only see 1 (or sometimes 0, depending on when the next runloop on the main thread is executed) outputs from `combineLatest`.

As soon as you remove the async call, you see the same output from `Future` and `Just`.

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let just = Just("Just")
let future = Future<String, Never> { promise in
    promise(.success("Future"))
}

just.combineLatest([1,2,3].publisher).sink { (value) in
    print(value)
}.store(in: &subscriptions)

future.combineLatest([1,2,3].publisher).sink { (value) in
    print(value)
}.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable, but in my case this Future is infact async, so I unfortunately cannot remove the asyncness.

Comment: @flashspys then your question is very different from what you've actually asked. `Just` and `Future` don't behave differently when you call `combineLatest` on them. The difference is caused by the async dispatch. You need to create a better [mcve] of your actual problem, since it seems you oversimplified your problem into something that doesn't actually represent your real problem anymore.